# How to maintain new loaded page even though the page is refreshing using jquery

Tags: jquery

Let say I have 2 pages,
The first page consist of form and after it has been submitted, I want to load a new page inside the same page (oldpage.html)

```
$("body").load("newpage.html");
```

The problem is when I'm trying to refresh the page it goes back to oldpage.html content

My question is, how to maintain the new loaded page even after refreshing.

Comment: you insert the new page using a server side language not ajax

Comment: If you want information to persist between page loads then you need to persist it somewhere.  Local storage, for example.  You could write some flag to indicate that the "new page" should be loaded.  In your page loading logic, check for that flag and adjust the page's content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use cookie for save page name for load:

```
function write_Cookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function read_Cookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function clear_Cookie(name) {
    write_Cookie(name, "", -1);
}




var page_for_load=read_Cookie('current_page');
if(!page_for_load){
    page_for_load='oldpage.html';
    write_Cookie('current_page', page_for_load, 1);
}

$('body').load(page_for_load, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt == "success"){
        page_for_load='newpage.html';
        write_Cookie('current_page', page_for_load, 1);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing entire body, you should just redirect to new page after submitting a form.
I would recommend after a form being submitted by POST, the server to redirect the client to the new page or back to the form. Use http code "303 See Other". This is the best way to redirect the user to a new resource using the proper GET method after the server handled a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use an *cookie*. However, for simplicity its easier to use the `sessionStorage` object.

**Note**:
There are two storage objects

1. [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) - data will be stored until the session is closed
2. [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - data can be stored forever

So what you could do is checking what page is stored inside the `sessionStorage`.

**For example:**

```
/**
 * This translates into
 *
 * if(sessionStorage.getItem("page")) {
 *     var page = sessionStorage.getItem("page");
 * } else {
 *     var page = "oldpage.html";
 * }
 */
var page = (sessionStorage.getItem("page") ? sessionStorage.getItem("page") : "oldpage.html";

// Load the correct view based on the above statement
$("body").load(page);
```

Don't forget to update the `page` when posting the `form`. This can only be done if using some library like `AJAX`. If server side, then a `cookie` would be better.

To [update](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) the `sessionStorage` object use.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("page", "newpage.html");
```

Comment: where to put the $("body").load(page) ? I put it under document.ready it gives me page flickering